# Fonts 2.1.0 and audio player 0.10.0 not working

Tags: flutter

i received the message

Because google_fonts >=2.0.0 depends on path_provider ^2.0.0 and audioplayers >=0.8.2 <0.12.0 depends on path_provider ^0.5.0, google_fonts >=2.0.0 is incompatible with audioplayers >=0.8.2 <0.12.0.
So, because xylophone depends on both audioplayers ^0.10.0 and google_fonts ^2.1.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because xylophone depends on both audioplayers ^0.10.0 and google_fonts ^2.1.0, version solving failed.)

can any only help on this .....

Comment: You will need to either upgrade your audioplayers package (It uses path_provider ^0.5.0) or downgrade your google_fonts package to an older version where it used path_provider ^0.5.0
Try upgrading audioplayers first, 
Change audioplayers in your pubspec.yaml to:
audioplayers: ^0.19.1

This may cause conflicts with other packages, please share your pubspec.yaml file if this happens

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.